# Will the browser parse / pre-render / paint display:none HTML?

Tags: html, css, dom, browser

I want to prevent the browser from doing the work to parse and pre-render or paint some "hidden" HTML until I'm ready to show it, so that I can quickly display a minimal set of content, having the browser only do the work the render the visible pieces.

**I'm looking for maximum render/paint speed of initial page load.**

My current HTML:

```
<div id="stuff">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="visible">
            <h1>Item 1</h1>
            <a class="details" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="invisible">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean elit mi, bibendum a imperdiet sed, imperdiet id leo. Mauris vulputate tellus id metus euismod, eget gravida libero ultricies.</p>
            <img src="/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="visible">
            <h1>Item 2</h1>
            <a class="details" href="javascript:void(0)">Show more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="invisible">
            <p>Vestibulum tristique fermentum dui, et pretium elit. Ut purus lacus, mattis vitae leo vel, congue mollis mi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum luctus, purus ut mattis ullamcorper, justo odio ultrices dolor, nec porta purus turpis sed orci. Aliquam orci sapien, dictum sed facilisis molestie, tempus in orci.</p>
            <img src="/img/2.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>

    ... and so on...
</div>
```

The actual "invisible" content is MUCH more significant than in this example, and there are 50 "items" per page.

My external CSS:

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

Will `display: none` in an external stylesheet prevent the browser from pre-rendering the hidden content?

Is there a better way to do what I want?  Should I put an inline style="display:none" on the div instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you measured the rendering speed when the HTML includes your invisible content, and then measured it after taking the invisible content out of the HTML? Is there much of a difference? Beware of premature optimisation and all that.

Comment: Won't `visibility:hidden` prevent the element from rendering, or am I making stuff up?

Comment: you can use web service for invisible part, so that this part render when click show more, otherwise it is not render

Comment: @tymeJV: The browser would still have to account for everything about the element as if it were visible, and make sure everything else around it flows according to those calculations. It can't just skip rendering the element and call it a day. A naïve implementation might even prerender the element as normal then just turn it invisible, and while that might be a permissible implementation, it's also clearly a waste of resources.

Comment: display none, no matter where/how will not reduce load time

Comment: @DavidNguyen - See my findings on the answer below.  You're wrong.  Display: none WILL prevent CSS from being applied to elements inside the containing hidden div.  This can actually increase perceived load time significantly.

Comment: @StevenMoseley load time and render time are two different things

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`display: none` will not prevent the browser from parsing/loading that markup and associated resources (EDIT by Steven Moseley: tested this and found that display:none will actually prevent the browser from painting the HTML, i.e. applying CSS to the elements inside the hidden div, and will only do the work to parse the HTML to construct the DOM, which will in fact give a performance advantage).  It is simply not rendered as part of the page flow until its `display` value changes.  Generally speaking `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` have little or no impact on page load time.  The main venue for optimization / performance with `display: none` involves selectively choosing when to display it since that triggers a reflow/rerender of page content, and even that is usually a negligible difference in all but very complex applications.

If you want to wait to load the content until it's needed, don't include it at all (or include empty div placeholders) and then use AJAX to fetch the content from the server once it's needed after page load and add it to the page with JS.  jQuery makes this very simple with its built in AJAX functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought, but unfortunately, AJAX isn't an option at this time.

Comment: @StevenMoseley ah that's too bad. In that case I'd say you're probably out of luck, although if it's an option to show less than 50 per page, paginating the list might help.

Comment: @StevenMoseley It also bears mentioning that there is a lot you can do to optimize page load speed outside of lazy loading content - minifying your JS/CSS of course, and basically anything else you can do to optimize/compress scripts, images and other resources.  The golden rule is ultimately "the less GET requests the better".

Comment: I just did a test on this to confirm.  Display: none is definitely SIGNIFICANTLY faster than display: block (though significantly slower than not rendering the HTML at all).  It looks like the browser IS parsing the HTML to construct the DOM, but IS NOT applying the CSS to the elements inside the hidden div until they're displayed.  This is kind of what I hoped for.  I also verified that the display: none can go either in an external stylesheet or inline for the same effect.

Comment: Yeah - GET requests for images, etc inside the `display: none` divs will still be carried out on page load, and it will all be parsed/loaded as part of the DOM, but I think it's not actually rendered until you change it to a visible `display` value, which then triggers a repaint/reflow of all content on the page.  Should probably add a disclaimer that it's been a while since I really dug into this optimization / rendering stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Can you avoid building the invisible HTML in the first place? Are you going to at some point set `.invisible { display: block }`?.

I've found `display: none` isn't as wonderful for performance as you'd expect. You're better off only adding the extra elements to the screen when your user needs them, with infinite scrolling or pagination.

Try and avoid putting HTML into the page if it's not going to be viewed, and just add what you need in 1 go to minimize DOM manipulation.

Is it likely a user will look at all 50 items per page?