# Prevent image downloading when it is hidden by css

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, optimization

I'm running some tests on how to prevent downloading image assets when they are hidden by CSS.

Some test results are confusing me and I'm looking for some help to find out the reason.

Assuming that there is a `<div>` to hide..

---

**Case 1.** both `background-image` and `display: none;`  are set to the `<div>`

*>> image gets downloaded*

**Case 2.** `background-image` is set to the `<div>`, and `display:none;` is set to its parent element.

*>> image not downloaded*

---

As far as I know, setting `display:none;` will remove the element from the render tree. So I wonder if it's the right behaviour to download the image on case 1, which I feel it should not.

Chrome works differently from FF, which doesn't download image on both cases.

I've been searching all over but I couldn't find satisfying answer why chrome works that way.

I'm attaching some articles I'm referencing.

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en
- https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/ (Test 2 and 3)

Any opinions will be appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Browser Rendering of display:none HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161886/prevent-browser-rendering-of-displaynone-html)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

By the way, display none don't remove the element from the render tree, in the way that the :nth-child() still counting those display none elements in the render tree.

I guess Chrome just does not go into those elements.